# How to access JavaScript object child array?

Tags: javascript

how would you access array values of a broader object like:  `MainObj.ExtProps = new Array();`

I have some existing code that is setting `key, values` on `ExtProps` for example a WebURL value.

How would you check `MainObj.ExtProps` for the `WebURL` value?

Comment: key value suggested to me that it's an object literal of some sort and not array... do you mean the array contains multiple key value objects like so: `[ { 'key' : 'value' }, {'key' : 'value' }]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExtProps to store (key, value) pairs, then it is a map, not an array.  You could do something like: `MainObj.ExtProps.WebURL = "url";` and then any time you want to access the url, all you have to do is something like `var url = MainObj.ExtProps.WebURL;`

Comment: thanks, I thought similar but am getting `undefined`

Comment: You have to define MainObj and ExtProps first.  `MainObj = {}; MainObj.ExtProps = {};` You must instantiate the objects before you instantiate fields within those objects.  Then you can do `MainObj.ExtProps.WebURL = "url";`